# unnesting list inside of a list, inside of a list, inside of a list... while preserving id in R

Tags: r, json, list

I imported a JSON file with below structure:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc6sC.png)

I would like to transform it to a dataframe with 3 columns: `ID`  `group_name`  `date_joined`,
where ID is a element number from "data" list.

It should look like this:

```
ID  group_name  date_joined
1   aaa     dttm
1   bbb     dttm
1   ccc     dttm
1   ddd     dttm
2   eee     dttm
2   aaa     dttm
2   bbb     dttm
2   fff     dttm
2   ggg     dttm
3   bbb     dttm
3   ccc     dttm
3   ggg     dttm
3   mmm     dttm
```

Using below code few times i get a dataframe with just 2 columns: `group_name` and `date_joined`

```
train2 <- do.call("rbind", train2)
```

sample file [link](https://easyupload.io/jv9gxe)

Comment: you should provide some sample data so people can better help you. You can use the `dput()` command to help.

Comment: you could try `rapply(train2,rbind)` but again, its hard to help without example data.

Comment: added sample file

Comment: you should share the output of `dput(train2)` or include the libraries and code you used to turn your json file into an R object. That way we will be able to reproduce your data exactly as you have it.

Comment: `train2 <- fromJSON("train.json")
train2 <- do.call("rbind", train2)
train2 <- train2[1:5,]
train2 <- list(train2)
exportJSON <- toJSON(train2)
write(exportJSON, "sample.json")`

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: i am using jsonlite()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following should work:

```
library(jsonlite)

train2 <- fromJSON("sample.json") 
train2 <- train2[[1]]$groups$data    

df <- data.frame(
      ID = unlist(lapply(1:length(train2), function(x) rep.int(x,length(train2[[x]]$group_name)))),
      group_name = unlist(lapply(1:length(train2),function(x) train2[[x]]$group_name)),
      date_joined = unlist(lapply(1:length(train2),function(x) train2[[x]]$date_joined)))
```

output:

```
> df
   ID                                                                            group_name                date_joined
1   1 Let's excercise together and lose a few kilo quicker - everyone is welcome! (Piastow) 2008-09-05 09:55:18.730066
2   1                                                                 Strongman competition 2008-05-22 21:25:22.572365
3   1                                                                      Fast food 4 life 2012-02-02 05:26:01.293628
4   1                                 alternative medicine - Hypnosis and bioenergotheraphy 2008-07-05 05:47:12.254848
5   2                                                                      Tom Cruise group 2009-06-14 16:48:28.606142
6   2                                                                  Babysitters (Sokoka) 2010-09-25 03:21:01.944684
7   2           Work abroad - join to find well paid work and enjoy the experience (Sokoka) 2010-09-21 23:44:39.499240
8   2       Tennis, Squash, Badminton, table tennis - looking for sparring partner (Sokoka) 2007-10-09 17:15:13.896508
9   2                                                                  Lost&Found  (Sokoka) 2007-01-03 04:49:01.499555
10  3                                                         Polish wildlife - best places 2007-07-29 18:15:49.603727
11  3                                                              Politics and politicians 2010-10-03 21:00:27.154597
12  3                                                                 Pizza ! Best recipes  2010-08-25 22:26:48.331266
13  3                                            Animal rights group - join us if you care! 2010-11-02 12:41:37.753989
14  4                                                                   The Aspiring Writer 2009-09-08 15:49:57.132171
15  4                                                              Nutrition & food advices 2010-12-02 18:19:30.887307
16  4                                                                       Game of thrones 2009-09-18 10:00:16.190795
17  5                                                  The ultimate house and electro group 2008-01-02 14:57:39.269135
18  5                                                              Pirates of the Carribean 2012-03-05 03:28:37.972484
19  5                                                 Musicians Available Poland (Osieczna) 2009-12-21 13:48:10.887986
20  5                 Housekeeping - looking for a housekeeper ? Join the group! (Osieczna) 2008-10-28 23:22:26.159789
21  5                                                             Rooms for rent (Osieczna) 2012-08-09 12:14:34.190438
22  5                                                   Counter strike - global ladderboard 2008-11-28 03:33:43.272435
23  5                                                              Nutrition & food advices 2011-02-08 19:38:58.932003
```

Comment: After `train2 <- train2[[1]]$groups$data` we have a list where each element is a single user. I want to preserve the element number as id, so i can  match group_names to users.

Comment: @Szym_Szym I've added another column to the new `df` that takes care of the `ID`. If this works for you please consider accepting the answer.